# NodeList in NodeList

Tags: java, xml, nodelist

I want to update tab.

> If 'rooms' <2 => 'balcony' => 'Y'

But in code I need to make research like this:
    update(id, name) - that should be method 
pseudo code which I`m trying to make:

```
1 search block where _ID=id
2 find _Name=name in block
3 check if 'rooms' <2 , if yes update <balcony> on 'Y' if its 'N'
```

Can anybody help me with it. I`m beginner with XML. No idea how to search nodeaList in nodeList. Thank you for every help.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<project_folder>
    <block _ID="39">
        <sector>1</sector>
        <buildings>
            <building _NAME="santana">
                <rooms>4</rooms>
                <balcony>N</balcony>
            </building>
        </buildings>
    </block>
    <block _ID="40">
        <sector>2</sector>
    </block>
    <block _ID="41">
        <sector>3</sector>
        <buildings>
            <building _NAME="orange">
                <rooms>1</rooms>
                <balcony>N</balcony>
            </building>
            <building _NAME="lemon">
                <rooms>3</rooms>
                <balcony>N</balcony>
            </building>
            <building _NAME="grape">
                <rooms>2</rooms>
                <balcony>N</balcony>
            </building>
        </buildings>
    </block>
</project_folder>
```

Comment: Welcome, you will get a (better) response if you attempt an implementation. Try putting `java xml` into your favourite search engine and start from there.

Comment: I can`t do this with my rank